# Why does extractHTMLStrip() from tm.plugin.webmining truncate strings under 61 characters?

Tags: html, regex, r, string, tm

I have a set of messages, some of which are plain text, others that are marked-up with HTML tags. The messages with HTML tags do not appear to contain the tags `<html>` or `<body>`; I've only seen `<p>`,`</p>` and `<br>` so far. I am trying to use `extractHTMLParse()` from the R package `tm.plugin.webmining` to remove the HTML tags from the strings that contain HTML, but the function fails for strings shorter than 61 characters (or 68 if the string contains html tags).

For example,

```
extractHTMLStrip("This message has 61 characters, sixty-one characters exactly.")
[1] "This message has 61 characters, sixty-one characters exactly."
```

but if I strip the period at the end, nothing is returned,

```
extractHTMLStrip("This message has 61 characters, sixty-one characters exactly")
character(0)
```

If I try it on a string with HTML tags, the minimum length jumps to 68:

```
extractHTMLStrip("<p>This string has 68 characters, sixty-eight characters exactly</p>")
[1] "This string has 68 characters, sixty-eight characters exactly"
```

The call fails if I strip the last character:

```
extractHTMLStrip("<p>This string has 68 characters, sixty-eight characters exactl</p>")
character(0)
```

I've googled "extracthtmlstrip minimum length" and searched the tm.plugin.webmining manual for the word "length", but neither of these offered a solution. StackOverflow seems to have just two (now three) questions that mention `tm.plugin.webmining`, but they don't mention this problem.

Can anyone explain this behavior and how I could strip HTML tags from strings of arbitrary length? Ideally, I would like to do this using a tool that understands HTML and not just regex's.

OS X 10.10.3, R version 3.1.2, and `tm.plugin.webmining` version 1.3.

Comment: This is a workaround (which feels more like a hack), but could you not simply wrap the string in `<p></p>` tags until the length is greater than the required minimum?

Comment: Until the accepted answer's solution is implemented, this is the workaround I'm using -- thanks for the suggestion, @TimBiegeleisen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug in the code.

The function calls `htmlTreeParse` from `XML`, which results in :

```
library(XML)
tree <- htmlTreeParse("whatever you entered", asText = TRUE, useInternalNodes = TRUE, encoding = "latin1")

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>whatever you entered</p></body></html>
```

The `<!DOCTYPE....>` is a generic header, put in by the function.

The following steps pull out the longest child, which happens to be the `<!DOCTYPE` string if you have a small input (it's 106 characters long, which is the length a 68 character long input goes to with the added tags), then it gets removed by the call to `xmlValue`, resulting in the `character(0)` output.

I've filed a [bug on their github](https://github.com/mannau/tm.plugin.webmining/issues/12).